# How to divide words with silent consonants?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, editing

I wonder how to divide words such as '*assumption*' at the end of line, when a consonant (in this case 'p') in the middle of the word is silent (/əˈsʌmʃən/).

Which syllable (and line) does the "p" belong to?

*assum**p**- tion*

or

*assum- **p**tion*

My guess is that the first division looks better because '*tion*' is a common suffix itself, but am not sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, find a dictionary that lists syllables.

Example:

> as‧sump‧tion  /əˈsʌmpʃən/
>   [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/assumption)

This pronunciation claims the *p* is not silent.

Comment: What if a one-syllable word comes in plural? Can I split like this: _**ditch- es**_? I'm asking, because I've heard that there should be at least three letters in the second line after the split?

Comment: "Rules" like that 3 letter thing will be part of your style guide, so consult it.

Comment: Last example and question. Merriam-Webster suggest _**man-i-fest**_. Which split do you think looks (and reads) better when the word becomes an adjective and one additional syllable appears: man-i-_**fest-ed_** or man-i-_**fes-ted_**?

Comment: Similarly, re·​con·​struct - should split into re·​con·​struct·​ed or re·​con·struc·t​ed?